# Replace missing fonts in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice

I have a Word document that uses fonts not available on my system. How can I globally replace these fonts? I've tried both Find/Replace (with formatting) and Tools / Options / OpenOffice / Fonts, but both of these only seem to support replacing one installed font with another -- typing the name of the missing font in manually doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can do this using the following dialog available under the ***Tools*** -> ***Options*** pulldown menu.

[image: ss#1]

This will replace the font *Arial* with *Caladea*, for example. I realize you said you tried this but these are the exact same directions as described here on Debian Wiki in this topic: [SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts](https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts), specifically in [this section](https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts#LibreOffice_font_substitution).

The key thing you have to do is, after making a mapping such as this, you're required to restart LibreOffice. I would assume the same holds true for OpenOffice too.

**NOTE:** You'll need to type any names for fonts that are not installed when filling out the above dialog.

Comment: I thought I'd tried that and it didn't work, but it turns out I just underestimated the number of different buttons I had to press to get it to apply. `:P`

Comment: This worked for me. Libre Office Draw. I had a pdf with fonts missing my system that showed up horribly. I opened it with Libre Office Draw, Tools > Options > Fonts then for me Font: Impact Replace With: Akkadian AND CLICK THE GREEN CHECK ICON to the right of Replace with. Check the Always and Apply replacement table as shown and when the Options dialog was OK clicked the font change was applied. When selecting the text the old Font name is still shown.

Comment: In Libre Office Writer there should be a better way. Edit > Find & Replace, clear the Search text, click Other Options, uncheck any Attribute selected, then . . click in the empty Search test, then Format, Font tab, select the Font name to replace. Click Find All and it should show info and highlight any matching text. Then click in the empty Replace with, then Format, Font tab, select the Font name to substitute. Click Replace All and it should do the replace. BUT I could not do a replace with the font that was missing on my system.

Comment: This doesn't work if the font is missing (not available on the system) :|

Comment: This worked for me: I had managed to get a font called "var ff-mono" to ruin my world and it caused major havoc with everything defaulting to "Liberation Mono". The trick is to enter the Missing Font Name with a Capital Letter I.E. Var ff-mono, else the little green tick wont appear.